# How is memory released in Android?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I am wondering how to decrease the java heap size in Android, and i read a few things about memory freeing in Android and i am wondering how they mesh together and if they are correct:

- I read somewhere that on devices where `isLowRamDevice() == false` the java heap doesn't actually shrink upon releasing memory, suggesting that this strategy might not actually work. I don't remember where i read this but the closest correlation i found between `isLowRamDevice()` and memory release is [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/low-ram) and this doesn't talk about this directly.
- After reading about Large Object Space (LOS) in ART i kinda understood that ONLY objects from that space get GC'ed and other objects don't upon releasing them (aka the java heap won't decrease in size when freeing objects that aren't in LOS).

  - LOS according to [this](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/art/runtime/gc/heap-inl.h#383) definition contains Arrays of primitives and Strings over a certain size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298354/how-is-memory-in-android-released

Comment: @MikeM. that's not an answer:)